# wifiManager.getScanResults() returns 0

Tags: java, android, handler, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to develop a software which scans available wifi networks in background with a handler thread.
The problem is when i use `handler.postDelayed()`, `WifiManager.getScanResults()` return 0 meanwhile in normal situation its working .

These are runtime permissions:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 87);
        }
    }
}
```

And my handler:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                counter++;
                scanWifi();
                scannWifiInterval();
                if(counter==5){
                    sum/=5;
                    textView2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                }
            }
        },timeoutSecondGenerator());
```

and the scanWifi method:

```
private void scanWifi() {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WiFi is disabled ... We need to enable it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        }
        arrayList.clear();
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning WiFi ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

And `BroadCastReciever`:

```
BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {


                results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                unregisterReceiver(this);



                for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){

                }
                for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
                    if (scanResult.SSID.equals(networkSSID)) {
                        sum+=scanResult.level;
                        textView.setText(Integer.toString(scanResult.level));

                    }


                }

            }
        }
    };
```

Logcat:

```
09-16 16:36:47.384 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.454 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.474 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.474 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:36:47.474 2536-2536/? E/ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=false mPausedForTransition=false
09-16 16:37:02.169 1478-1849/? E/WifiStateMachine: result: -1266999764, Moved BSSID: 80:2a:a8:9a:ea:da
09-16 16:37:02.269 2681-2692/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:905778253>, App: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow
    pez: Error when calling server.
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):279)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24)
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629))
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148)
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):254)
        at wwt.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):15)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1324)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1412)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:481)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:368)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at yod.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):32)
        at imu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):1)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):109)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24) 
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629)) 
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148) 
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):254) 
        at wwt.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):5) 
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) 
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
09-16 16:37:02.419 17764-17764/? E/Zygote: no v2
09-16 16:37:02.489 2681-17697/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:905778253>, App: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow
    pez: Error when calling server.
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):279)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24)
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629))
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148)
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):254)
        at wwt.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):15)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1324)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1412)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:481)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:368)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at yod.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):32)
        at imu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):1)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):109)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24) 
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629)) 
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148) 
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):254) 
        at wwt.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at cgv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):5) 
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) 
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
09-16 16:37:02.499 2400-17412/? E/VelvetNetworkClient: Failed to get auth token
09-16 16:37:02.589 2400-17412/? E/UpdateGcmReg: Network error while trying to register for GCM updates
09-16 16:37:03.320 2681-4954/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:905778253>, App: com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/playatoms
    pez: Error when calling server.
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):279)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24)
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629))
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13)
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148)
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16)
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33)
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69)
        at gjc.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):4)
        at gjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at gjb.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at gja.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):1)
        at gkz.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
        at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):15)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1324)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1412)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:481)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:368)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:476)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:118)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:249)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at yod.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):32)
        at imu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):1)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6)
        at gnj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2)
        at gnx.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):109)
        at gnx.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):24) 
        at gnx.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629)) 
        at gmi.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):34) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):13) 
        at ift.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):148) 
        at iet.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):16) 
        at ieq.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):33) 
        at dhb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):69) 
        at gjc.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):4) 
        at gjb.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):2) 
        at gjb.c(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):6) 
        at gja.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):1) 
        at gkz.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):8) 
        at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214) 
        at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113) 
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387) 
        at djf.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@13280016@13.2.80 (040304-211705629):3) 
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
09-16 16:37:03.350 17542-17787/? E/Isotope: UID: [10104]  PID: [17542] HygieneTask : GetArchiveDownload RPC failed
    eer: UNAUTHENTICATED
        at bai.b(PG:6)
        at baf.call(PG:9)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at bke.run(PG)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2138)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(AccountManager.java)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1996)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-16 16:37:03.350 17542-17789/? E/Isotope: UID: [10104]  PID: [17542] HygieneTaskService : Archive Prefetching failed
    eer: UNAUTHENTICATED
        at bai.b(PG:6)
        at baf.call(PG:9)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at bke.run(PG)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2138)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(AccountManager.java)
        at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1996)
        at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
09-16 16:37:03.370 2681-14277/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
09-16 16:37:03.390 2681-14277/? E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
09-16 16:37:03.420 1478-1632/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
09-16 16:37:03.700 1478-1632/? E/NativeLibraryHelper: Failed to load assets verifier: 0
```

keeps scanning but finds nothing

minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 28

and i run it on samsung galaxy s9

I would be grateful if anyone answers.

Comment: Can you give more details? Which phone are you running this on, what version of android, can you include logcat

Comment: @Shmuel minSdkVersion 17
                 targetSdkVersion 28 and i run it on samsung galaxy s9

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find the problem.
I just changed targetSdkVersion from 28 to 22 and it worked!
I think on some android devices runtime permissions is not the answer and you need to set it on manifest file as well and in sdk 28 program only sets runtime permissions.